# Is there a jQuery event for when the page changes?

Tags: jquery, onchange

I'm beginner on Jquery and trying to get used to it. Is there any event that I can bind to the page to stop my slider timer?

What I want to do is, when a user changed page or goes to another tab, I want to catch that event. Is there any event or listener for this system?

Answer (score 2):

I would go with `onbeforeunload` instead of `unload` in order to give you maximum time. However, if you plan on making a request back to the server at this time (or do anything asynchronously), you may find yourself in a race condition, where sometimes the request makes it through, and sometimes it doesn't.

That happens because the page stops handling your request (or other async action) when it unloads. This can be almost immediately in modern browsers, and fairly quickly in older IEs. It very rarely makes sense to do something in any of the `unload` or `beforeunload` events, because of this.

If you are trying to pass timer information to the next url, you might just modify urls when they are clicked.

```
$('a').click(function(){ this.href=this.href + "#timer=" + timerVar; });
```

Then when you get to the next page, you can read that last value from the url.

Google analytics solves this problem by adding a delay to all links:

```
$('a').click(function(){
  var that = this;
  setTimeout(function(){
    window.location=that.href;
  },100); 
  return false;
});
```

This just gives your page extra time to follow links. It's not foolproof though, but that doesn't matter for google since analytics are somewhat transient (and they also use the url params for other more important matters (e.g. campaigns)).

Comment: Thanks for answer Alex. But I guess you got me wrong. I made a simple slider by jQuery. And it has a timer. What I want to do is, stop the timer, if a user goes to another tab, another site, or goes to some other browser. I want to catch that event like many OOP lets you to control these events by "focus in" or "focus out". But as I read jQuery docs, they use focus for elements not for the entire page itself. Maybe I'm wrong. Like I said I'm a beginner on jQuery.

Comment: My answer addresses how you would stop the timer, and then send the information to the next page on your site. Then you can continue to handle that event when the new page loads.

Comment: As I understand (correct me if I'm wrong) this codes sends the current time to "my" other page. But what I want to do is catch an event when user "focus in" something else. some other website some other browser, local files anything.. just when a user "focus out" of my page. Also thank you very much for giving answers and trying to help

Comment: oh, that's a bit more difficult. I see what you mean, though. I think lots of old browsers support `window.onfocus` and in newer browsers you might be able to figure it out by using `requestAnimationFrame` which only fires while the window is focused. That is a pretty big hack though. Your call.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this: http://api.jquery.com/unload/

Comment: Thanks Sam, but its not triggering as it says. I mean I tried to change the page, use back and forward buttons. But it's not triggering even the sample on the link you have given. Do I need to add some more codes?

Comment: If you are having problems seeing these events, that's because they fire, and then the console clears to show the new page. Most consoles (firebug and webkit) have an option to not clear out old logs after page unloads. You'd need to use those settings.

Comment: Modern Webkit browsers like Chrome and Safari does not support this unload method.

Comment: I just want to stop my timer when user goes to a different tab or goes to check his/her folders or something. For using less memory and cpu. In most OOP you have focus out methods but couldnt find a working one for jQuery

Answer (score 0):

http://www.webkit.org/blog/516/webkit-page-cache-ii-the-unload-event/ this blog post should help you on this..

Comment: I tried this method too.. Actually that makes more sense for me. Javascript is easier than jQuery but still its not triggering.